# Vue-Router named route fallback

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I am building a project in VueJS and Vue-Router.
Altough it is working well, I would like to know if there is a fallback option when a **named** route can not be found.
I do have a catch-all route for a 404 page which works as expected when typing an invalid URL.

```
const router = new Router({
  linkExactActiveClass: 'active',
  mode: 'history',
  routes: [
    {
      path: '*',
      components: {
        header: AppHeader,
        default: NotFound,
        footer: ContentFooter
      },
    },
  ]
});
```

However, when a component in a named router-link can not be found, the user just sees a completely blank screen.
For example, a router-link with a non- existing component like this:

```
<router-link class="nav-link" :to="{ name: 'someNameHere' }">
    Click here!
</router-link>
```

results in a blank screen with the warning `[vue-router] Route with name 'someNameHere' does not exist` logged in the console.

Is there a way to make the catch-all/fallback component work in this case as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a design decision by the authors of the router because this is a development error.  With that being said, you could use a route guard to check if the route exists before navigating to it.  Something like:

```
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  if (to.matched.length < 1) {
    next(false);
    router.push('/404');
  } else {
    next();
  }
});
```